# Does a set and a transitive reflexive relation on that set form a category?

Tags: category-theory

If you have a set $S$ with a relationship on it $R$.  With $R$ being transitive and reflexive can it be considered a category with elements of the set being the objects and the relationship being the morphisms?

Comment: I'm guessing that you posted this from a cellphone. You might want to check your post for "damn you autocorrect!" issues.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks combo of auto-correct and agraphia

Comment: No, it can't, some assumptions on $R$ are needed.

Comment: I think it can be a category if the relation is transitive and reflexive and you assign a morphism $s_1$ to $s_2$ $f_{s_1,s_2}$ such that $f_{s_1,s_2}(s_1)=s_2$ if $s_1Rs_2$ and equals to 0 else.

Comment: Apparently, you put the assumptions on $R$ in the title but not in the main text. Then yes: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/preorder

Comment: @alejo added the assumptions to the text as well as the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a standard example called a *preorder category*.  ( A preorder is a reflexive transitive relation.)

We take the objects of $\mathcal C$ to be elements of $S$.

There is an arrow $(a,b)$  from $a$ to $b$ if and only if $a≤_R b$; if it exists the arrow is unique. Then the identity arrow for $a$ is simply $(a,a)$.

The composition of arrows $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ is the arrow $(a,c)$.  The composition obviously has the required associativity and identity properties.